# Dragging image out of frame removes it from the kineticjs stage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Could someone please provide me with the a jsfiddle of a simple and clean way to remove an image from the canvas by dragging the image out of the canvas frame.

Here is what I could come up with http://jsfiddle.net/n4w44/50/ :

I make the stage 400px and put the frame in the center at 200px by 200px dimensions by implementing the `dragBoundFunc`.

```
  var image = new Kinetic.Image({
       draggable : true,
        x: 175,
        y:175,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        draggable: true,
         dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
            var stage_width = stage.getWidth();
            if (pos.x > 300 || pos.x < 100 || pos.y > 300 || pos.y < 100)
            {
              this.hide();
            }
            return {
              x: pos.x,
              y: pos.y
            };
          }
    });
```

But it would be nice to see alternative solutions which:

- Make it look cleaner as the image is exiting
- Allow me to avoid having to do some ugly offsetting of the container (which I would need to do when I embed it in the page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you're using an older version of KineticJS (4.4.3)? The reason I ask is because as of KineticJS 4.5.1 (and now currently we're on 4.6.0 which you can get on the [KineticJS Website](http://kineticjs.com/)) the **Tween** class was added in favor of the **Transition** class.

[KineticJS 4.5.1 Changelog](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log#451-may-11-2013)

Anyways, I solved your problem by adding some code to the `dragBoundFunc`

```
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
             draggable: true,
             x: 175,
             y: 175,
             width: 50,
             height: 50,
             draggable: true,
             dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
                 var thisImg = this;
                 if (pos.x > (frame.getWidth() + frame.getX() - thisImg.getWidth()) || pos.x < frame.getX() || pos.y > (frame.getHeight() + frame.getY()  - thisImg.getHeight()) || pos.y < frame.getY()) {
                     var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                         node: thisImg,
                         duration: 0.1,
                         opacity: 0,
                         onFinish: function () {
                             thisImg.hide();
                             thisImg.setOpacity(1);
                         }
                     });
                     this.stopDrag();
                     tween.play();
                 }
                 return {
                     x: pos.x,
                     y: pos.y
                 };
             }
         });
```

To make the image exit smoother, I used a Tween to *tween* the opacity to 0, making it look like a quick fade effect. When the tween finishes, I hide the image and set the opacity back to 1 so you can show the image later without any complications. `.stopDrag()` is used to the stop the image from dragging while the Tween is played.

To make the `dragBoundFunc` more dynamic, instead of using static numbers we use the **x,y** position of the frame along with the **width & height** to calculate the boundaries, and we also need the width and height of the image to subtract from the boundaries so that the `dragBoundFunc` takes into consideration the offset of the image (which is by default the top left).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/fYXaN/) **Note**: In the fiddle I replaced the KineticJS 4.4.3 version with **KineticJS 4.6.0** (see the HTML code)

It's up to you if you can upgrade your KineticJS version to use Tweens, or stick with the version you have now and use Transitions (which you'll have to find documentation for, I'm not sure how they work).

Comment: Thank you! Although I had to get rid of `stopDrag()` as it was preventing subsequent images from being draggable.

Comment: Oops, maybe `this.stopDrag()` should've been `thisImg.stopDrag()`.  Also, see the differences between [stopDrag()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Rect.html#stopDrag) [setDraggable()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Rect.html#setDraggable) [getDraggable()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Rect.html#getDraggable).